# DbFunctions, is a type which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I tried to use the `SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffDay` but `DbFunctions _` says

> CS0119: DbFunctions is a type which is not valid in the given context

```
SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffDay(this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions _, DateTime.Now, i.Invoicedate) + i.ProductNav.GracePeriod.GetValueOrDefault()
```

I also tried the following but i get the same error

```
SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffDay(DbFunctions _, DateTime.Now, i.Invoicedate) + i.ProductNav.GracePeriod.GetValueOrDefault()
```

Comment: please, give us more info about your error, stack trace, error message, steps to reproduce etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateDiffDay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffday?view=efcore-6.0) is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). You call it with object instance and then pass the parameters without that object as a first parameter. In your case:

```
EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(DateTime.Now, i.InvoiceDate) + i.ProductNav.GracePeriod.GetValueOrDefault();
```

You may need to add the using directive:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

and the needed nuget package

Comment: This isn't strictly true; nothing stops you calling an extension method as if it were a normal method, and providing a first argument of whatever you would have called it on

Comment: @CaiusJard Just because it isn't the only way to invoke the method, doesn't make it not true. Yes your way is possible too, but you can also invoke it using reflection and pass just the name of that method. The way I described it is the standard way of invoking extension methods, and OP was asking why they get compiler errors when they pass the correct number and type of parameters to DateDiffDay method.

Answer (score 3):

[Take a look at these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.functions?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-ef-functions)

> Provides CLR methods that get translated to database functions when
> used in LINQ to Entities queries. Calling these methods in other
> contexts (e.g. LINQ to Objects) will throw a NotSupportedException.

You can only access it in linq to entity queries, you can't do what you're trying to do.

it's an extension method you can't pass it in.

```
public static int DateDiffDay (this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions _, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
```

on DateDiffDay

you use it like this         DateDiffDay(starDate, EndDate) in the query

```
var allDaysDifferences = myEntities.Sum(r => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(r.FromDate, r.ToDate));
```

Comment: *you can't pass it in* - this isn't strictly true; nothing stops you calling an extension method as if it were a normal method and providing a first argument of whatever it was you would have called the extension method on

Comment: @CaiusJard  Thanks for your comment. Sorry for the confusion. When I said you can't pass it in as an argument I was talking about how he was trying to pass in the type operator argument of the extension method.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are what you *would* ordinarily do but I think it worth pointing out that where they imply an extension method is some sort of magical thing that can only be called in a certain way, that isn't really true

Nothing stops you calling an extension method as if it were any normal static method; you just have to provide some instance to call it on as the first argument

Here is an extension method:

```
public static string NoL(this string x){
  return x.Replace("l","");
}
```

Note the `this` on the first argument, making it an extension. You can either call it "on a string" or pass it a string:

```
var hw = "Hello World";

var heoword1 = hw.NoL());
var heoword2 = Ext.NoL(hw);
```

In probably all cases you'd do the first form, because static method extensions exist to make the code more compact and readable, but there's technically nothing wrong with your attempt to call the method you did, you just didn't provide a valid first parameter. This would work:

```
SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffDay(EF.Functions, DateTime.Now, i.Invoicedate)
```

EF.Functions being the instance you would ordinarily just call DateDiff on:

```
EF.Functions.DateDiff(DateTime.Now, i.Invoicedate)
```

--

So when *would* you use an extension method like a normal one? Probably not many places, but it may make sense if its signature exactly matches some method that accepts a delegate.

For example, suppose we had an extension method:

```
public static class Exts{
  public static string CombineStringAndInt(this string s, int i){
    return s+i;
  }
}
```

It takes a string and an int. LINQ's `Select` has an overload that accepts a delegate that has arguments of `string,int`. You could call the method above like this:

```
var arr = new[]{"a","b"};

arr.Select((s, i) => s.CombineStringAndInt(i));
```

But nothing prevents you calling it like this:

```
arr.Select(Exts.CombineStringAndInt);
```

Because it *is a method that accepts a string and int*, which is what is demanded by the `Select` overload that accepts a delegate for a list item and the index it's at

There's nothing magical or weird about the extension method that prevents it being caled like this, or limiting it to only being used in a `instance.ExtensionMethod(arg2,arg3..)` style